# Why is my 1 to 1 copy of the w3schools ajax database tutorial only pulling the first set of data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to figure out why my 1 to 1 copy of the w3 schools ajax data base pull example is only pulling the first customer worth of data. The code I am running is a 1 to 1 copy of w3 schools with my server info in place of theirs. I added their same info that they display to my database.

I made a 1 to 1 copy of the following exercises at w3 schools.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_database

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_database.asp

I created a copy of the database.

[image: Database copy]

I made the front end to be a perfect copy of their front end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<form action=""> 
  <select name="customers" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a customer:</option>
    <option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
    <option value="NORTS ">North South</option>
    <option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>

<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "getcustomer.php?q="+str);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I added in my own server info in place of the nottelling, noway, notachance and nope:

```
    <?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("nottelling", "noway", "notachance", "nope");
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
  exit('Could not connect');
}

$sql = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country
FROM customers WHERE CustomerID = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['q']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($cid, $cname, $name, $adr, $city, $pcode, $country);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>CustomerID</th>";
echo "<td>" . $cid . "</td>";
echo "<th>CompanyName</th>";
echo "<td>" . $cname . "</td>";
echo "<th>ContactName</th>";
echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
echo "<th>Address</th>";
echo "<td>" . $adr . "</td>";
echo "<th>City</th>";
echo "<td>" . $city . "</td>";
echo "<th>PostalCode</th>";
echo "<td>" . $pcode . "</td>";
echo "<th>Country</th>";
echo "<td>" . $country . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

After all that,

The first customer pulls, but the table elements are not brought over to the html.

[image: 1st Customer Pull]

Then if I try to pull the second customer, it gives the header data, but fails to pull from the database.

[image: 2nd Customer Pull]

The third pulls headers, but, also fails to pull data from the database.

[image: 3rd customer pull]

I followed the tutorial faithfully with the exception of taking a / out of the second customer code, removing spacing from the data in the fields (which was causing the import to fail until I did it) and finally I changed some of the zipcodes to remove dashes and spaces just to see if it would help (when trying to import the database).

Am I failing to follow this tutorial in some way?
Is there another tutorial that could better illustrate this stuff to me?

Comment: `console.log(str)` in your function showCustomer(str) ` and in your PHP use `file_put_content($_GET['q'])` to make sure your endpoint receive something.

Comment: @Patfreeze I think you mean `echo $_GET['q'];`

Comment: The code looks OK to me.

Comment: Where should I be doing the echo? In the php file?

Comment: In the PHP file, right before or after the table.

Comment: Ok, I did both and reuploaded, the console.log() is showing for each one https://ibb.co/WF0PchT the echo isn't doing anything. I placed it below the last echo on the php file.

Comment: Make that into `console.log(str, str.length)`, and see what you get then. You said you modified the data you loaded into the database, regarding spaces - so maybe one of these values still has extra whitespace somewhere, that makes the comparison in the query fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved! There were spaces in the MySQL database that slipped in when I did the csv import. Spaces before and after value.

After removing the spaces, this was fixed.